# Keystone js: Is there way to remove Manage button from one of the model?

Tags: node.js, keystonejs

I want to remove mange button from one of my model. I am able to remove from all the model by making code changes in ListManagement.js file but not able to remove from single one . Is there any solution for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the properties of your model to be uneditable and undeletable. This prevents anyone from you (or anyone with access to the code & your database connection information) from editing properties of a model, or entire models, that you don't want them to. It's a better solution than removing the ability to manage all models entirely. If you want to prevent users from editing all of your models, just set the below options.

`noedit` - (Boolean) Prevents editing of items in the list through the Keystone Admin UI

`nocreate` - (Boolean) Prevents creation of new items in the list through the Keystone Admin UI

`nodelete` - (Boolean) Prevents deletion of items from the list through the Keystone Admin UI

`hidden` - (Boolean) Hides the list in the Keystone Admin UI

http://keystonejs.com/docs/database/#lists-options

These options are specified upon model creation, and can be enabled per-model.

Comment: Hi Shea thanks for reply... the issue I am facing is I need to remove multiple delete and edit option from one model not the individual delet option. That is why I want to remove manage button. If I used nodelete: true it will remove individual delete option also ... do you have solution to remove multiple delete option

Comment: So you want to prevent people from deleting multiple documents, but want to keep the ability to delete individual documents? Or is it the other way around? The options i described apply to the entire list and all documents within the list.

Comment: Yes I want to keep ability of individual delete option.Do you know any solution for that ?

Comment: I don't think so; `nodelete` restricts the option for the entire model. You'd have to edit the source of Keystone itself to get that to work, and I don't know if that's an option for you if you don't check Keystone into your version control.